# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter works on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am using AVPlayer in my app.MPNowPlayingInfoCenter works fine for simulator. But on real device its not working for control screen music Play/Pause buttons.

Comment: Could you please add more detatils? What _its not working for control screen music Play/Pause buttons_ actually means?

Comment: When you slides up the screen you will see the music control  button like Play ,Pause, Forward and rewind button. When I play some audio from my app then these button should work accordingly like When I click on Pause then My audio should paused. 
I hope I have made you clear.

Answer (score 0):

To enable remote control events, you should use [beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents) on [UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/). Example:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

If at some point you want to stop receiving events, call:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().endReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

To handle remote events you should implement [remoteControlReceivedWithEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:):

```
override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent) {
    // Your implementation
}
```

Comment: Do you use: `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter()`?

Comment: yes. i am using MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: .mixWithOthers)
```

Please stop! You should remove .mixWithOthers option. Please prefer

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
```